# Find a basis B of R2 such that the matrix of the linear transformation T(x, y) = (y, x) is diagonal with respect to B, and give the diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis $B$ of $R^2$ such that the matrix of the linear transformation $T(x, y) = (y, x)$ is diagonal with respect to $B$, and give the diagonal matrix.

This is the question. I'm not really sure how to begin with this one. Anything would help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We're looking for a basis $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

$T(x_1,y_1)=(y_1,x_1) = \alpha(x_1,y_1) +0(x_2,y_2)$

$T(x_2,y_2)=(y_2,x_2) = 0(x_1,y_1)+\beta(x_2,y_2)$

We get:

$y_1=\alpha x_1$ and $x_1=\alpha y_1 \Rightarrow y_1=\alpha^2y_1$

Since $\alpha \neq0$ (why?), we get $\alpha=\pm1$. In the same way we get $\beta=\pm1$.

In order to get two linear independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we will choose $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=-1$.

So let's look at $B=\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$. That's a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (why?).

Can you continue from here?